# Is there a way to delete a stale machine worker from a Hybrid Worker Group in Azure automation account?

Tags: azure, automation, worker, hybrid

I have inherited the following situation :Azure Automation account with Hybrid Worker Group and a single Hybrid Worker inside. The machine on which this worker was installed has been decommissioned and doesn't exist anymore. The problem is that it's name is still present in the Hybrid Worker group. The GUI doesn't provide me with a way to delete just the worker. I can only delete the whole group. Is there a way to delete only that stale worker machine and preserve the group?

Answer (score 1):

Remove-HybridRunbookWorker cmdlet is part of the
HybridRegistration.psd1 module. This module is being installed with the
script New-OnPremiseHybridWorker.ps1 during registration of a new
machine as a Hybrid worker. When I imported it in a standard powershell
console on a non-registered as a worker machine, and tried to run this
command, I got this error:
"Remove-HybridRunbookWorker : Machine not registered"
So the first problem is that in order to be able to delete a worker machine from Azure, we have to have another worker machine.
Since I intended to create a new worker machine
anyway, I did just that and tried to delete the stale machine in Azure
from the new one. This time Remove-HybridRunbookWorker command with
-Verbose switch said that deletion was completed. Yes but no. The old
worker machine stays in Azure in it's Hybrid workers group.

Well as surprisingly as it sounds, putting the new worker machine into
the same hybrid worker group as the stale machine did the trick. Verbose
logs in the powershell console were exactly the same, but this time the
ghost machine disappeared from the worker group. So to answer my
question in the first post: 1. Create a new worker machine in the
same hybrid Worker Group as the machine you want to delete. Use the
"New-OnPremiseHybridWorker.ps1" script. 2. From the new machine run Remove-HybridRunbookWorker using the "-MachineName" parameter.